# Can't create a new app on fresh install of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm attempting to create a new app on a fresh install of Rails and it gives me a 'permission denied' and then *a lot* of other stuff before just not working at all.

I've tried to look for an answer but it there doesn't seem to be an easy to find answer at all. This is what my Terminal looks like:

```
    Zach-Beckers-Computer:rails_projects Zach$ rails new first_app
      create  
/Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir': Permission denied - /rails_projects/first_app (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:51:in `block in invoke!'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `call'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:114:in `invoke_with_conflict_check'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:50:in `invoke!'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions.rb:95:in `action'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/actions/empty_directory.rb:15:in `empty_directory'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:103:in `create_root'
    from (eval):1:in `create_root'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `block in invoke_all'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `each'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `map'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124:in `invoke_all'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:226:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.2/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:19:in `load'
    from /Users/Zach/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

I don't know what I need or what I need to do. I should mention I'm running OSX Lion (10.7) on a Macbook pro that is 1 year old.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you're trying to create a rails app in your root directory when you should be in your "home" directory. In OS X that'd be /Users/Zach. Do this:

```
cd ~/
mkdir rails_projects
cd rails_projects
rails new first_app
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! That worked! I wonder why this tutorial had me creating it in the root.  Since I'm the only user/admin on this computer it never crossed my mind that a folder created in the root wouldn't have write access.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be a weird oversight. Are you certain the tutorial said `mkdir /rails_projects` and not `mkdir rails_projects`? The first attempts to create in root and the second is relative to your current path which would generally be your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have write access into the directory you're trying to create your Rails app. Make sure the directory belongs to your user with `chown` and make sure you have write permissions into that directory with `chmod`.